# Time Complexity of Recursive Program to find all subsets of an array - of a given length (k)

Tags: python, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I made a program to find all subsets of an array to length K.
Im having trouble finding the time complexity of it, since the recursive call is within a for loop.

I think It's not theta, since the program can terminate, so I'm assuming Big O, but as far as time complexity - It's hard to tell. Any thoughts or guidance? Thanks!

```
myarr = [1,2,3]
k = 2
finalarr = []
def subsets(n, k):

    if k == len(n):
        if not n in finalarr:
            finalarr.append(n)
        return

    for i in n:
        aux = n[:]
        aux.remove(i)
        result = subsets(aux, k)

        if not result in finalarr and result:
            finalarr.append( result)

subsets(myarr, k)
print (finalarr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the original set by `N` and its cardinality by `n`.

In each recursive call to the function `subsets` an element of the set `N` is eliminated, until we are left with a subset of length `k`. In other words, each subset of `N` is obtained by selecting an ordered `n-k`-tuple from `N`. The number of ways to do so is:

[image]

This could also be verified by plotting the call tree to the function `subsets`: first level consists of a single call, next level consists of `n` calls, then `n-1` calls and so on until the last level which has `n-k+1` calls. As the number of operations in the function `subset` (other than the recursive calls) is constant, we can simply multiply the number of calls in each level and get the aforementioned expression.

Two points to note:

1. This is not the most efficient algorithm, as each subset is produced several times. For example, the subset `(1)` of `(1, 2, 3)` can be produced either by first eliminating 2 and then eliminating 3 or vice versa.
2. The code contains the following condition:

   ```
   if not result in finalarr and result:

       finalarr.append( result)
   ```

   This condition is never satisfied as the function `subset` always returns
   `None`. These lines of code are thus redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Optimal time complexity to find all subsets of an array - of a given length (k) is equal 2 to the power of k. The explanation is to consider every element of the array in two possible states: belongs or not belongs to a subset. The tricky thing is to remember about an empty set. Here's an example: https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/images/power-set.svg